# Opening multiple different apk's inside the main apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I have an app which contains 3rd party apk's for users to download and install on their Android phones. But I would like to have a mechanism through which my users can open those apk's inside my app itself without the need to download them separately on their phones. Is it possible?

Comment: Put them in assets.

Comment: Can this be done dynamically somehow?

Comment: What do you mean with dynamically?

Comment: Means if I keep adding apk's to my list, I don't want my users to need to update each time on their end.

Comment: To your list? I said to assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not be a good choice as keeping those apk files inside your application will increase size of your own application. One good approach to put those apk files on your own server and give a download link in the application for each apk.

Comment: That's the thought. I want to provide a list view on the first page of the main app. User can click on a listview item and that apk should load. I will host all apks on the server but I need dynamic access. The main problem is how to open the apks on my server inside the app itself!!